# Valid to use assignment operator in C expression?

Tags: c, syntax

Instead of

```
cardNumber = j+1;
deck[i][j] = cardNumber;
theDeck[k] = cardNumber;
```

is it valid to just say

```
deck[i][j] = theDeck[k] = cardNumber;
```

to assign cardNumber to both deck and theDeck at the same time??

Comment: What does your compiler tell you when you try it?

Comment: Yes - the value of an assignment expression (x = y) is whatever's being assigned to x

Comment: you might get a compiler warning on some compiler settings (not sure about the example case, but certainly for gcc if you assign inside an if statement, which is related).  you can work around the if expresison case with double parens:  `if ((status = func(...))) goto exit;` (the warning isn't because you're doing something "wrong", but because it looks like == was the intended use).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.  The assignment operator returns a value.

Comment: Or, how I would say it: "The assignment operator is an expression." That is, it sets it apart from "an assignment statement" found in other languages like Python. C merely allows (all?) expressions in "statement context". (Python allows `x = y = 42` but not `x = (y = 42)` showing that it's just a special statement construct.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's an expression and its value is the right side of the assignment. Note that this comes also from the associativity of `=` (right-to-left), which makes this:

```
x = y = z
```

Equivalent to:

```
x = (y = z)
```

But not:

```
(x = y) = z /* wouldn't work */
```

So you can go even further and write:

```
theDeck[k] = deck[i][j] = cardNumber = j+1;
```

Comment: does this mean that parenthesis can be used to determine precedence for the entire line?

Comment: @brianSan yes, they can. But it's not needed, since the operator associativity already does that. `x = y = z = a` is just the same as `x = (y = (z = a))`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is; it is like this:

```
deck[i][j] = (theDeck[k] = cardNumber);
```